# Creating a custom Javascript Library at build-time

Tags: javascript, requirejs

**Background**

I have a javascript library that runs on a customers website. This library is a mixture of standard components (error handling, message passing, etc), and per-customer based custom components (specific dom handling routines).

**Problem**

I am breaking DRY. For each customer, I have the same code duplicated. Since I violate DRY, I am stuck with all the pitfalls: e.g. if I need to make a change to a common component, I have to replicate that change across multiple files.

**Desired Solution**

I'd like to separate out all the functionality into components, and selectively choose (via build script) the components that get added into the library.

*This would be somewhat similar to how Bootstrap allows you to mix and match javascript plugin functionality*

Example: CustomerA's library, needs the Base Component, the Comment Component, and a custom handler to parse Google Analytics.

CustomerB's library, needs the Base Component, and a custom handler for their shopping cart experience.

**I think I can do this with RequireJS, but is there a more industry standard way to build customized javascript libraries?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came across [Browserify](http://browserify.org/), which allows you to use Nodejs module system to create reusable components, in addition to using NPM node modules.